# I am finally planning on moving from console based game to PC gaming and have a few questions

Tags: computer-building

1. How often will I need to buy a new nvidia gpu
2. How can I make my new pc future proof to play any new games. Reason for asking is that I've had a friend who built a nearly a $4000 PC back in 2012 in the hopes of making it future proof with the latest i7, nvidia gpu and other hardware components at this time but he has trouble playing some new current pc games.
3. 32GB of DDR4 be considered future proof?

Comment: No such thing as future proof.  Some components may last longer compared to others, that's about it.  Your mileage may vary.

Comment: "32GB of DDR4 be considered future proof?" - NO;  "How often will I need to buy a new nvidia gpu" - Depends on the requirements of the specific programs.  "at this time but he has trouble playing some new current pc games." - **This is to be expected from a 5 year old PC.**  Your friend has a GPU from around 6 generations ago.  A GPU from 2012 is basically garbage compared to a GTX 1070

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. That depends.
2. That depends too, and is actually rather impossible.
3. That depends also.

First, If you're going to play triple-A titles at their release at maximum settings, you'll want to upgrade your GPU when you find your current GPU is unable to play these games at the settings you desire. At the same time, if you play triple-A titles a couple years after release, you'll want to upgrade your GPU when you find your current GPU is unable to play these games at the settings you desire. No, it's not confusing, and yes it means that it depends on you, your budget, your games, etc.

Next, because technology continues to advance, there is no such thing as "future-proof" when building a computer. For the same reasons consoles are iterated and upgraded and superseded and replaced, computers do the same. The difference being that a single high-end component for a computer can easily cost as much as an entire console, and sometimes much, much more.

Finally, 32GB of RAM is overkill for just about any game today, but that does not mean it will not be too little in a few years' time.

And a point of opinion: If your real name is Uncle Moneybags and you are filthy rich, you might be able to maintain a cutting-edge powerhouse computer at all times. But the odds are more likely that you're a normal person with a normal budget: PC gaming at the types and levels that your question assumes is exceedingly expensive. If you're a professional gamer who can fund your habit and needs: great. But a professional gamer is unlikely to be asking the questions you've asked here. More than likely your primary constraining factor will be your budget, and that's what depends most of all.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. I think I will stick to console gaming.

Comment: @answerSeeker Even consoles become outdated. Eventually the games will stop being made for a console and you will be forced to switch too.

Comment: Yes but not as often as pc gaming where the gpu has to be upraded.

Comment: @answerSeeker I disagree. You are replacing at a slower rate than consoles because a console you have to replace the entire thing where a PC you can replace a few components at a time.

Comment: Yes but the price of a single high end GPU is often more than a simple ps4 or xbox. Also, I've been able to play new ps3 games from 2008-2014. And PS4 games from 2014-2017. I don't know how many times I'd need to upgrade a system component if I needed to do the same thing on PC

Comment: @answerSeeker Also not true. You can get a $100-$130 card that will perform fine for most "modern" games. You aren't comparing apples to apples either since the "high end card" performs much more effectively than the console one does

Comment: You pay for what you get. PC gaming is more expensive, if you only consider gaming. But it doesn't have to be terribly expensive given that cutting edge is not the only choice out there. Console gaming is cheaper but generally also less capable (the Xbox One X will be roughly equivalent to a 2 or 3 year old computer in bare hardware specs, but accomplishes more because the software is designed to handle fewer tasks and to do them better).

Comment: I think all in all there is no right answer because nobody ever compares apples to apples like I was saying. If you compare the "same" performance parts of a console on a PC and have an OS designed only for gaming (say Steam box) then we would actually be comparing evenly. I will leave it at that though because there is no point in arguing which is right. It is a personal preference